# Loading both http and https for js scripts

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have an application, I can access them with http or https : `http://www.test.com` and `https://www.test.com` In the header of application I load an script for publicity : `http://www6.smartadserver.com`. If I access the application with http : the publicity are loaded. If I access the application with https, I get the error :

> The page at htttps://www.test.com was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script http‍://www.smartadserver.com. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

In the header of application I have :

```
<script src='http://www6.smartadserver.com/config.js?nwid=11111' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    sas.setup({ domain: 'http://www6.smartadserver.com', async: true, renderMode: 0, inSequence: true });
</script>
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<script src='//www6.smartadserver.com/config.js?nwid=11111' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    sas.setup({ domain: '//www6.smartadserver.com', async: true, renderMode: 0, inSequence: true });
</script>
```

Section 4.2 of [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2) provides for fully qualified URLs that omit protocol (the HTTP or HTTPS) altogether. When a URL’s protocol is omitted, the browser uses the underlying document’s protocol instead.

So, in usual words, you can avoid strictly setting protocol - and browser will select it automatically.

Comment: Maybe you could explain it a bit to OP? +1